# JSON to Console Applicaton, how to read it into C#?

Tags: c#, json

I'm a rookie and this is my first post, that said here is my question.

I'm doing a test in which I have a bunch of information, info about Persons, Companies to name a few, and then in each of these "headings" there is information.

I don't know (despite spending a day trying to read similar questions online, don't get it) how to read the document into C# console application and then store it temporary (no persisting) so I can work with it? (Maybe I shouldn't even use console application but that's what I'm working with right now).

I've put the info below, not sure how to attach a document here.

```
Persons = [{
"Name": "Anna",
"PersonalIdNumber": "720220-1111",
"Id": "13cf4bc2-92a3-4700-b697-fc9fbffe7143"
},
{
"Name": "Bertil",
"PersonalIdNumber": "820923-2222",
"Id": "048f4ad0-a6fd-4119-b965-56113ac516de"
},
{
"Name": "Cecilia",
"PersonalIdNumber": "620405-3333",
"Id": "107f7ab5-a613-4e10-8538-bc4eb0e75ebc"
},
...
}]
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Where is the document to start with? Is it in a file? Are you asking how to read a file, or how to parse the JSON? Have you tried using Json.NET?

Comment: I would assume every search for working with JSON and C# will provide a link to Newtonsoft's JSON library, which is the most used way to handle JSON in .NET

Comment: Hi, the info is in a file, notepad right now. In the file, first is the info about persons ,then in the same file there is info about companies. 

I can download the nuget newtonsoft json but then I don't know what to do. 

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The document seem to suggest that I already have the info in C#, it's now in an external file. So first question is how I get it into C# from the notepad file, divided up or not into the classes I have created I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Newtonsoft.JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) Library, install its [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) on your project, with NuGet Package Manager

As per it's main page:

```
using Newtonsoft.JSON;
...
string json = @"
[{
     'Name': 'Anna',
     'PersonalIdNumber': '720220-1111',
     'Id': '13cf4bc2-92a3-4700-b697-fc9fbffe7143'
 },
 {
      'Name': 'Bertil',
      'PersonalIdNumber': '820923-2222',
      'Id': '048f4ad0-a6fd-4119-b965-56113ac516de'
 }]";

 List<Person> Persons = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(json);
```

**Update**: you can consult more than 100 examples [here](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Samples.htm)

Obviously you have to declare a class that matches your JSON object, so you can both serialize and deserialize instances of this c# class to JSON.

```
public class Person
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
     ...
}
```

Comment: Okey ,installed the NuGet, then I don't know what to do next.

Comment: I've declared classes already, but then I have no idea what to do. I've read through other examples, watched youtube clips but I still don't understand. 

Company class looks like this for instance (not sure how to get it to look like code instead of running text): 

   class Company
    {
        public Company(string companyName, int organizationNumber)
        {
            CompanyName = companyName;
            OrganizationNumber = organizationNumber;
        }

        private string CompanyName { get; set; }

        private int OrganizationNumber { get; set; }

Answer (score -1):

Here is what I was after.

```
static List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
var jsonTextPersons = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Filepathblablalba\Persons.txt");
persons = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(jsonTextPersons);
```

Regards